# Extract the IN and OUT in one COLUMN

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the IN and OUT of the employee in one table. I am using php and mysql here, once I click the button the IN and OUT of the employee will be extracted from mysql table and display it in hmtl table.

This is my table
employee

```
emp_id | emp_name | transID  | TIMESTAMP           |
  1    |  Xavier  |  Log in  | 2014-04-11 07:00:00 |
  1    |  Xavier  |  Break   | 2014-04-11 09:30:00 |
  1    |  Xavier  |  Meeting | 2014-04-11 14:30:00 |
  1    |  Xavier  |  Log out | 2014-04-11 16:00:00 |
```

This must be the output after click the button,

```
empid | emp_name  | LOGIN    |  LOGOUT   |
  1   | Xavier    | 07:00:00 |  16:00:00 |
```

Thank you very much.
Helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the date from db you need:

```
select t1.emp_id, t1.emp_name, DATE_FORMAT(t1.timestamp,'%T'), DATE_FORMAT(t2.timestamp,'%T') 
from employee t1, employee t2 on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id and t1.transId='Log in' and t2.transID = 'Log out'
```

Comment: Thanks jogesh_pi, I will try your query.